# use jquery select2 plugin with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2

I am modifying SPA using angularjs. I want to use jquery select-2 plugin with it. how to use the plugin with angularjs ? Data is coming through ajax so i want these data to populate the select. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Angular's wrapper for Select2

[select-ui](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select)

You could also try with ui-select2 that is now deprecated in favor of the above ui-select (which I recommend)

[Deprecated - ui-select2](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2)